# Can I use in my Web app Spring and JSF together

Tags: java, spring, jsf

In my web app I use Spring MVC

Can I add to my app JSF to use Ajax
and what of them is better to work with Ajax?

Please not that I'm beginner in Java EE.

Thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can . Check out spring webflow with Primefaces JSF 2.0 Components examples they can give you some ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Spring has [support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf) for using JSF as your view technology. You don't need JSF to do Ajax though. You can do Ajax with your existing Spring MVC controllers.

Comment: indeed, if Ajax is the only concern , JSF is not a must

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Spring in Action book, there is a chapter about Spring-JSF combination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use, chk Jeremy Grelle two part [one](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/intro_spring_faces_1.html) [two](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/intro_spring_faces_2.html) series.

Also, I found the Javabeat tutorial easier to follow [JSF](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/232-integrating-spring-web-flow-with-jsf-1.html)